Notation $\le_{a,b,n,\ldots}$ in Analysis
In modern Analysis, especially Functional Analysis, one proves, or one uses inequalities of the form
$$F(X)\le_{a,\ldots,n}G(X).$$
The meaning of the subscripts in the inequality sign means that there exist a positive finite number $C(a,\ldots,n)$ (often called a constant!) such that
$$\forall X,\qquad F(X)\le C(a,\ldots,n) G(X).$$
Typically, the parameters $a,\ldots,n$ stand for the dimension of an ambient space, the size of the objects $X$ (e.g. size of matrices), etc ... The value of the constant is usually not as important as its finiteness.
Examples:

Sobolev embeddings,
Strichartz estimates,
Grothendieck Inequality, ...


Who was the first to employ this notation? When, and in which paper?


This is exactly what is called "Vinogradov's notation", except Vinogradov notation uses the symbol $\ll_{a,\dots,n}$ rather than $\leq_{a,\dots,n}$. An advantage of using $\ll$ instead of overloading the symbol $\leq$ is that one can write just $f(x)\ll g(x)$ without any subscript to mean $f(x) \leq C\cdot g(x)$ for some constant $C$, and that $C$ does not depend on any additional parameter. This would not work with $\leq$!

To add context for other readers: in analysis of PDEs many authors use the symbol $\lesssim$
to mean what you describe. That is slightly better than using the symbol $\leq$ with subscripts, as often one does not want to write the subscripts every time. Also, there are cases in which the constant C does not depend on any parameter.
